# What are the Moderation/Editing/Participation badges?

Tags: support, badges, election

For each candidate for the election, the number of badges Moderation/Editing/Participation are listed.
Going the badges section of the help center did not help in figuring out exactly which badges count as being under those categories.

Comment: I will just point out that alongside the *number* of the badges, you can also see the list of badges of the given type earned by a candidate in a *tooltip*. Just hover with your mouse over the 6/6, 8/8, etc.

Comment: @MartinSleziak maybe you could give that as answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the details can be seen in Shog9's answer on Meta Stack Exchange: [What are the details on the “candidate score” which shows during an election?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252641#252643)

I will just add that if you look at a specific candidate, you can see also list of their badges in a specific category in a tooltip if you hover over the number of badges (such as 5/6, 6/6, 8/8, etc.) Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot with the tooltip]

I will point out that this categorization (into moderation, editing and participation badges) is different from the one [in the list of badges](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges).

As you found out [in the election chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55082292#55082292), the ElectionBot can also list those badges.